# illegal start of expression error in Java for main()?

Tags: java

```
public class BottlesOfBeer {
  public static void countdown(int bottles) {
    if (bottles > 0) {
      System.out.printf("%d bottles of beer on the wall,\n", bottles);
      System.out.printf("%d bottles of beer,\n", bottles);
      System.out.printf("ya' take one down, ya' pass it around,\n", bottles);
      bottles -= 1;
      System.out.printf("%s bottles of beer on the wall.\n", bottles);
    } else if (bottles == 0) {
      System.out.println("No bottles of beer on the wall,");
      System.out.println("no bottles of beer,");
      System.out.println("ya' can't take one down, ya' can't pass it around,");
      System.out.println("'cause there are no more bottles of beer on the wall!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Wait, you can't have negative bottles...");
    }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int bottles = 99;
        countdown(bottles);
      }
    }

Error: illegal start of expression [Line: 18]
```

I am new to Java and I don't understand why I get this error when I compile it. This program supposedly countsdown from 99 to 1 then prints again when bottles = 0.

Comment: Which is line 18?

Answer (score 2):

you didn't close `countdown` method, which makes the `main` method become part of it. add closing `}` above the main method.

and thanks for reminding me of the days when I manually counted brackets....

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing curly brace '}' to close your "countdown" method. Add one on line 18.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a close braces after `else` block

```
else {
      System.out.println("Wait, you can't have negative bottles...");
    }
} // add this to fix the compile error
```

or you can omit `{}` for one line statements

```
else
      System.out.println("Wait, you can't have negative bottles...");
} // close braces of countdown method
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to close your `cowntdown` function, and, if you want your bottles variable to count down, you need to loop this.

```
public class BottlesOfBeer {
  public static void countdown(int bottles) {
    for(int i = bottles; i>=0 ; i--){
      if (bottles > 0) {
        System.out.printf("%d bottles of beer on the wall,\n", bottles);
        System.out.printf("%d bottles of beer,\n", bottles);
        System.out.printf("ya' take one down, ya' pass it around,\n", bottles);
        bottles -= 1;
        System.out.printf("%s bottles of beer on the wall.\n", bottles);
      } else if (bottles == 0) {
        System.out.println("No bottles of beer on the wall,");
        System.out.println("no bottles of beer,");
        System.out.println("ya' can't take one down, ya' can't pass it around,");
        System.out.println("'cause there are no more bottles of beer on the wall!");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Wait, you can't have negative bottles...");
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int bottles = 99;
    countdown(bottles);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the curly braces of the following else statement:

```
else { 
      System.out.println("Wait, you can't have negative bottles...");
    } 
}// Fix
```

If you are very much new to coding, you can use Notepad++. With this you would easily avoid such mistakes.
Happy Learning!